# Как отправлять и получать электронную почту в NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, imap

Неужели нет какой то простой библиотеки, чтобы запустил

```
var email = new Email()

// получаем почту
email.on('mail', function(mail){   })

// отправляем почту
email.send('ololo@gmail.com', 'Заголовок' , 'Текст')
```

и всё работало.

Я не хочу регаться в gmail, а потом просить GMAIL отослать от моего имени письмо, я хочу САМ СВОИМ СЕРВЕРОМ отсылать и ПРИНИМАТЬ письма. Неужели такого еще не изобрели?

Comment: Почта это адски сложный древний и кривой протокол.  Проще воспользоваться чём-то готовым, а не писать свою кривую имплементацию

Comment: С другой стороны, беглое гугление находит https://haraka.github.io/

Comment: @AlexeyTen да я понимаю, но я так и не понял как пользоваться харакой. как я понял есть nodemailer и у него есть модуль smtp-server который и занимается не только отправкой но и приёмом почты